# Can I declare variables in-line instead of at the top of a function?

Tags: delphi, variables, declaration, pascal

I have used visual basic about 5 years ago.

but i have started using delphi 5 years ago (when most developers jumped from delphi to visual studio) delphi is as easy as vb and at the same time it is rad and robust.  Delphi is having many changes since pascal (eg : strings must be combined in a different way in pascal instead of just using + ) in order to make scripting faster.

but why in delphi we have to declare var on top , when i am writing many statements for a procedure i have to scroll up and declare a var and come down again. delphi is one of the best(some times one and only) MOST RAPID'est' IDE in the world but why they did not give support to declare variable anywhere just as in vb c# etc

Comment: Pascal was designed that way, and it is even more strict than what Delphi became (i.e. Pascal enforces the type/const/var sequence, IIRC it does not allow to mix them like in Delphi). You may not like it or not, but it is designed to have clear declarations and separate them from code.

Comment: Now you can: https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-october-inline-variables-delphi.html  In my opinion looks a bit un-pascalish but can be handy after you get used with them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Delphi version 10.3 Rio it is possible to declare variables and constants [inline](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Inline_Variable_Declaration).

Even the type can be inferred.

Examples:

```
procedure Test1;
begin
  var i : Integer;
  i := 10;
  WriteLn(i);
end;
```

Variables can be inlined and assigned:

```
procedure Test2;
begin
  var i : Integer := 10;
  WriteLn(i);
end;
```

Inlined variable types can be inferred:

```
procedure Test3;
begin
  var i := 10;
  WriteLn(i);
end;
```

Scope of inlined variables can be limited to begin/end blocks:

```
procedure Test4;
begin
  var i : Integer := 10;
  WriteLn(i);
  if i < 20 then begin
     var j := 30;
  end;
  Write(j); // <- Compiler error “Undeclared identifier: ‘j’”
end;
```

Inlined variables can be used inside `for-in` or `for-to` loops:

```
procedure Test5;
begin
  for var i := 1 to 10 do
    WriteLn(i);
end;
```

Constants can also be inlined and type can be inferred as normal constants:

```
procedure Test6;
begin
  const i : Integer = 10;
  const j = 20;
  WriteLn(j);
end;
```

Comment: How can it be that a question from 2010 is answered on 2018-11-27 refering to a Delphi version that didn't exist in 2010 and is immediately marked as accepted?

Comment: @dummzeuch, I don't know what you mean with immediately. It took about 18 hours, but what is your point?

Comment: My point is that a question from 2010 when Delphi 2009 was the current  version, cannot be answered referring to Delphi 10.3 which was released in 2018 and that answer be accepted as correct. It should at least mention that inline variable declarations are not available in any of the older versions.

Comment: @dummzeuch, if someone would search for the possibility to declare variables inline in Delphi, it would be strange if this answer would be excluded from such a question in this Q/A site.

Answer (score 16):

It is possible to declare a var in the middle of a procedure using a code template and that is also enabled by default with Live templates in newer Delphi versions.

I just type `var` and then press CTRL+J and enter the name and type the IDE does the rest.

No big deal for me.

A demonstration of live templates by Mike Rozlog:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40284

Comment: Never even knew that! :-) Still not going to use it, though... Most of my methods are short enough to just scroll up 8 lines and add the var there, right before the begin.

Comment: I am also trying to keep my methods short, but you seldom know before you actually implement the code what variables you need, so the code template function of the IDE helps to interrupt the programmer ;).

Answer (score 15):

If you have to scroll, your method is too long and probably needs to be refactored.

That said, in recent versions of Delphi [you can declare a variable without moving your cursor by using the refactoring system](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declare_Variable_and_Declare_Field_Overview_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: +1 for pointing to the real problem. You should strive to make your functions: small, with as few arguments as possible and do only one thing.

Comment: -1 for that statement is simply not true. There usually are a lot of procedures in a project that make sense to be longer than one screen high.

Answer (score 11):

Even better than Jens' Ctrl-J shortcut is this.

1. Write your code, e.g.:

   ```
   I := 0;
   ```
2. Notice that "I" has a red squiggly line under it (meaning it is undeclared).
3. Click on "I" and type the shortcut:  Shift+Ctrl+V
4. Up will pop a declare variable window which usually will have figured out the correct type for you.
5. If necessary change the type and hit enter to close the window.

I love this shortcut and use it all the time.

Comment: You can just start with Shift+Ctrl+V and do things in the more traditional order as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+V is extremely useful but never worked (or worked randomly) for me. The Delphi IDE was always buggy as hell.

Answer (score 10):

You asked this question: "why they did not give support to declare variable anywhere just as in vb c# etc"

Here's the answer:  Because the language designers feel that declaring variables inline is confusing and difficult to read.  If all variables are declared at the method level, their declarations are easy to find and their types are easy to determine. They believe that inline declarations make it difficult to track variables and their type.

Other language designers prefer the ability to declare variables inline, but a clean demarcation between code and variable declaration is one of the reasons many people prefer Pascal.

Comment: I think that could be a nice argument in favor of declaring variables at the top of a method but I don't think this is actually the reason why Delphi inherited the Pascal way of declaring variables. As far as I know, this is related to language design decision to allow for a simple way to implement a fast single step top-down compiler.

Comment: @Trinidad --You are correct, compiler speed is also a factor here.

Comment: @Nick - And some languages don't need declarations at all. Variables are dynamically figured out. But declaring them is better, because then compilers can optimize them properly.

Comment: I don't buy the argument that Delphi's way of doing things is easier to read. Especially to those coming from a heavy object-oriented background. And more important than readability, is the isolation of variables, which is essential to object oriented design. If I want to use **x** explicitly inside a for-loop, **x** should be entirely _inaccessible_ to anything outside that loop. Recall the importance of local over global scope. I'm leaning more in favor of Trinidad's response.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy  -- That's fine.  As I tell my kids -- everyone is different.  I prefer the Pascal way, and find the code easier to read.   Your mileage may vary.